# I'm running an game emulator and it keeps crashing with connections

Tags: c#

Okay, so I run a game emulator and it didn't close connections so I searched around on here and found some coding to replace it with

```
    private static SqlDatabaseClient CreateClient(int Id)
    {
        Int32 returnId = 0;

        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(GenerateConnectionString()))
            {
                connection.Open();

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    returnId = Id;
                }

                return new SqlDatabaseClient(Id, Connection);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Connection.Close();

                    if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        returnId = Id;
                    }

            }
        }
    }
```

but when I place that in I get an error

> "Error    1   'AGame.Storage.SqlDatabaseManager.CreateClient(int)': not all
>   code paths return a
>   value C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Emulator\Storage\SqlDatabaseManager.cs   204 35  AGame"
>   and that line is "private static SqlDatabaseClient CreateClient(int
>   Id)"

Comment: Have you ever search your error message on Google? It returns 209k results by the way. https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=c%23%20not%20all%20code%20paths%20return%20a%20value&rct=j

Comment: your catch doesn't return anything.

Comment: How would I fix the catch for returning?

Comment: @IlluminatiOwnsMe, Add `throw;`.

Comment: How about simply _not_ catching anything?

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments above you should change the catch block to:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Trace.Write(ex.Message);
  throw;
}
```

Also, are you sure your finally block is valid? What is the 'Connection' object?